# Setting a theme in WPF

Tags: wpf, themes

I have a relativly simple question that I can't seem to figure out. I have downloaded some theme files in an XAML format off the internet and I would like to use them as my themes in my WPF application. How do you do this? All help is appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

Add the theme.xaml file to your project(right click->Add Existing Item...). Then in your App.xaml file add the following code

```
<Application.Resources>
<ResourceDictionary Source="ThemeFile.xaml" />
</Application.Resources>
```

Replacing ThemeFile.xaml with the name of the theme file you wish to use.

Comment: When I ran the program after the changes, there seemed to be not changes to what i had originally

Comment: use DynamicResource instead of StaticResource

Answer (score 1):

You can put the elements in App.xaml, and they'll automatically trickle down.  This can either be done directly (copy and paste), or via a [merged resource dictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa350178.aspx), where app.xaml just references the .xaml file(s) of your theme.