# adding theme xaml to an existing wpf project

Tags: c#, wpf, themes

please help me add a XAML theme file to my WPF project. I have an exisiting theme.xaml file.
Is there a way that the whole project (controls etc') accend the theme, so I wouldn't change control after control?
tnx guys

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Setting a theme in WPF](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2549795/setting-a-theme-in-wpf)

Comment: in uwp there is themeresource that you can use. in wpf I think you have to use staticresource or style.

Answer (score 0):

The basic direction you have to go is to create styles and resources without names. Only control types. By doing so you will set the same style on all controls of "that" type and it will affect your entire view.
Also, search and use a resource dictionary and apply it at the top of the tree so it will apply to the entire application.